# Custom shaped form control

Tags: c#, winforms, pixel, shapes

I have very very little knowledge in C# and I am trying to make a WinForms application to create 8x8 pixels monochrome bitmaps. I want the user interface look like below:

[image: Form]

Here, each of the black bordered boxes will represent a pixel, and simply when user click one of them, it will be filled with black so a "pixel would be set".

I looked for a way of converting standard button control to a custom shape, but could not find an elegant way. I don't want to create these black boxes programmatically, if possible. How can I create such black boxes that will act like a toggle button?

Note: I created the sample picture using graphical design tool and Visual Studio, it is not from a real application. It is the target I want to achieve. There will be other form elements to control the created bitmap in the final application.

Comment: Let's ignore those gray dots between the square..

Comment: That looks like a simple class that defines a Rectangle. A `bool Selected`,  `Color BorderColor` and `Color FillColor` properties with a *manager* class that handles the `List<RectangleClass>`, defines the size of the gaps and toggles the `Selected` value when `Rectangle.Contains(Point)` on a `Mouse.Click` event. The `Paint`/`OnPaint` event of the container can pass the `e.Graphics` object to the *manager* class that paints all the Rectangles in their current state.

Comment: And once you have the custom calss or an image checkbox  you can programatically put them in a 2d array so you can easly get x,y coordinate

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are looking to use a `CheckBox` control.
You want the following properties (don't worry it can be set in the property grid it's only to show the actual property and values) :

```
CheckBox myCheckBox = new CheckBox();

// change the look to a button style
myCheckBox.Appearance = System.Windows.Forms.Appearance.Button;

// put white background to match your design
myCheckBox.BackColor = System.Drawing.Color.White;

// make button style flat to get rid of the 3d-esque look
myCheckBox.FlatStyle = System.Windows.Forms.FlatStyle.Flat;

// either center image or scale should look good
myCheckBox.BackgroundImageLayout = System.Windows.Forms.ImageLayout.Center;

// set to your empty picture by default and on the checked changed you will swap that
myCheckBox.BackgroundImage = /* whaever image is default */;
```

then on the checked changed event just change the background image. The check box as it does allow 2 states you will be able to nicely use the `Checked` property to know the status which is easier to handle that having a button and storing a value for each.

Comment: This is the exact answer I was looking for. Looks like very simple point but since I am noob on C#, it was hard for me to find. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

This could be done with a standard button. You would need to set the button's `FlatStyle` property to `Flat`, and empty the `Text` property, and add a `Click` event. Each button's click event can then be mapped to the following method:

```
private void Pixel_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
  ((Button)sender).BackColor = ((Button)sender).BackColor == Color.Black
    ? Color.White
    : Color.Black;
}
```

The button can easily be resized in the IDE to make it square. You would also set the initial colour to either white or black in the IDE.

Comment: you should change all isntances of `Pixel.` to `((Button)sender).` the sender will be the button itself and if he create many buttons he could then map this event to all the buttons instead of writing one for each.

Comment: @Franck Thanks, I've updated the answer to include that.

Answer (score 1):

First I created 1 button.
In the properties of the button set the following:

```
FlatStyle = Flat  
FlatAppearance => BorderColor = Black  
FlatAppearance => BorderSize = 4
```

Then copy and create 63 more button and arrange like your picture.
[image]

For each button create a click event and you do like the following code so that when clicked it will make the background color to black. If the background was already Black it will set it back to white.

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (button1.BackColor == Color.Black)
    {
        button1.BackColor = Color.White;
    }
    else
    {
        button1.BackColor = Color.Black;
    }
}
```